# Best approach to deal with complex nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form with products in rows and suppliers in columns. Users can enter an order quantity for each product / supplier combination.

[image]

For each Supplier, 1 Order is created. Each Order contains OrderItems. OrderItems are created for each field (Product / Supplier combination) where the user enters a quantity.

There's a lot of handwritten code to process the submitted form.

Is there any way to DRY up any of the code below?
Or is there a better approach altogether?

I checked out the Nested Forms Railscast but I don't see any way how I could use accepts_nested_attributes_for here because the input is two dimensional (combination of supplier and product).

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base    
  has_many :order_items
end

class Supplier < ActiveRecord::Base    
  has_many :orders
end

# groups all OrderItems for 1 Supplier
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base    
  has_many :order_items
  belongs_to :supplier

  def self.create_orders_and_order_items(orders)            
    orders.each do |supplier_id, order_items|
      if order_has_order_item?(order_items)
        order = create!(
          :total => 0,
          :supplier_id => supplier_id,
          :order_group_id => order_group.id
        )        
        OrderItem.create_order_items(order, order_items)                
        # update attributes
        order.update(:total => order.order_items.sum(:total))        
      end      
    end
  end

  def self.order_has_order_item?(order_items)
    sum = 0
    order_items.each do |product_id, quantity|
      sum += quantity.to_i
    end
    sum > 0 ? true : false    
  end    
end

# 1 OrderItem per product / supplier combination
class OrderItem < ActiveRecord::Base    
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :supplier
  belongs_to :product

  def self.create_order_items(order, order_items)        
    order_items.each do |product_id, quantity|
      if quantity.to_i > 0                        
        order_item = create!(
          :quantity => quantity,
          :product_id => product_id,
          :order_id => order.id,
        )

        # update after creating, because methods called below are only available once object has been instantiated
        order_item.udpate(:total => order_item.calculate_total)
      end
    end
  end  
end

class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    Order.create_orders_and_order_items(params[:orders])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to :action => "index" }
    end
  end
end

# view: _form.html.erb
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <% @suppliers.each do |supplier| %>
      <td COLSPAN=2><%= supplier.name %></td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
  <% @products.each do |product| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= product.name %></td>
      <td><%#= some price %></td>
      <td><%= f.text_field "#{supplier.id}[#{product.id}]", :value => "" %></td>
    </tr>
</table>  

<%= f.submit %>

# params (from memory)
{"orders" => {
  "4" => # supplier_id, 1 Order for each Supplier
    { "13" => "2" } # product_id => quantity, = 1 OrderItem
  }
}
```

Comment: where exactly do you need nested attributes, I see a form for order with several fields. I suppose you are adding OrderItem's to an Order, right?

Comment: hmmm you loop through all `@products` are these OrderItems, I suppose not.

Comment: Yes, I'm adding OrderItems to each Order. No, Products are not OrderItems. The form lists Products. OrderItems are created where a Supplier / Product combination has a quantity of != nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering to

> Or is there a better approach altogether?

I strongly suggest using a **Form Object** which is basically extracting the complexity of dealing with a form using several AR models in a separate class.

Check the [7 patterns to decompose fat AR models](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/) Section 3.

Answer (score 1):

Loop through all products does not seems what you should do in this case. I would add `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in Order model.

This would make you delete your `create_orders_and_order_items` and `create_order_items`.

Also, I would use a [validation for quantity](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods.html#method-i-validates_numericality_of) in OrderItem model.

I am not sure if your code works like this: you get to your page and see a list of all products and then you can enter quantity for each product.

Instead of this, you should have addable/removable entries, and in each entry allow user to select product and quantity. This is done with `accepts_nested_attributes_for` and your way could be facilitated by [nested_form](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form).

Comment: Didn't know about validation for quantity, thanks for the link and post.